# How to delete all devices from Azure IoT Hub using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-iot-hub, azure-cli

I have an Azure IoT Hub with a bunch of devices that our team's E2E tests generate. I want to purge the Hub every once in a while using the Azure CLI.

I am running the Azure CLI locally on **Powershell**, using the [Azure IoT extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension).

From my research, there is a way to get a list of all the devices in a hub printed to the console in JSON format:

```bsh
az iot hub device-identity list --hub-name "test-hub"
```

And there is a way to delete a single device-identity:

```bsh
az iot hub device-identity delete --device-id "test-id" --hub-name "test-hub"
```

How can I delete all the devices in the hub using the cli interfaces and some powershell commands?

Comment: Can you show a sample output for ```az iot hub device-identity list --hub-name "test-hub"``` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run a For loop in PowerShell.

First install the Azure CLI for Powershell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'
```

Then add the Azure IoT extensions modules for PowerShell, log in to Azure, and change to the appropriate subscription (change `<subscription_id>`) :

```
az extension add --name azure-cli-iot-ext
az login
az account set -s <subscription_id>
```

After that, run the following Foreach loop which will delete all devices (change `test-hub`) :

```
$iotHubName = "test-hub"
$json = az iot hub device-identity list --hub-name $iotHubName
$devices = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
Foreach ($device in $devices)
{
  az iot hub device-identity delete --device-id $device.deviceId --hub-name $iotHubName
}
```

Note: This is an extremely slow process as of 2019. You can follow the progress by looking up the IoT devices in the main portal.azure UI.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem possible today with just one command. The underlying REST interface (which is what the cli and everything else uses) also does not have a bulk delete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/deletedevice

The IoT extension Github has some automation samples: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension/blob/dev/docs/scenario-automation.md

There they mass-create devices using a simple for loop. You can probably reuse some of that and combine it with the `az iot hub device-identity list` command

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @silent, the Azure IoT Hub supports an *Export/Import Devices* bulk job described in the blob. 
Have a look at the following links:

[Iot Hub Resource - Import Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/importdevices)

[Import devices example – bulk deletion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt#import-devices-example--bulk-deletion)

Basically, calling the *Export Devices* will create a blob of all devices, then updating this list for each device with an *ImportMode.Delete* mode, the blob is ready for invoking an *Import Devices* bulk job. 
In the case when all devices are well-known deviceIDs, the *Export Devices* step can be skipped and using a predefined input blob.

Note, that the bulk job is a long running background process, so we can used polling its status or using an Azure Event Grid for IoT Hub eventing. Deleting 100 devices will take approximately 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, building on @goamn's answer, but using `ForEach-Object -Parallel`:

```
$iotHubName = "test-hub"
$json = az iot hub device-identity list --hub-name $iotHubName
$devices = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$device | ForEach-Object -Parallel { az iot hub device-identity delete --device-id $_.deviceId --hub-name "test-hub" } -ThrottleLimit 10
```

Some notes:

- Requires Powershell 7+
- The `az iot hub device-identity list` call only seems to return 1000 devices. Maybe there's a way to return all of them, I haven't investigated as I only have 2000 to delete.
- The parallel script block doesn't seem to be in the same scope as the `$iotHubName` variable for some reason (also haven't investigated), so you need to add the hub name there as well.
- Running this in parallel can lead to lock file issues and other errors. But hey, if it works and deletes 90% of the devices 10 (or 50?) times faster then you're still ahead, right? Rinse & repeat until they're all gone.